# filewatchersystem is not firing the events after sometime

Tags: c#

Below is my code, I am running a windows service, but if i kept ideal for long time 5 or 6 days after that it stops firing events. though my service is running.Please help me on this

```
 private FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
 public bool StartFileWatcher()
        {
            _logger.Info("StartFileWatcher File watcher started");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_fileWatcherTargetPath))
            {
                _logger.Error("StartFileWatcher Directory name is null or Empty");
                return false;
            }
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(_fileWatcherTargetPath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(_fileWatcherTargetPath))
            {
                _logger.Info("StartFileWatcher Directory Created " + _fileWatcherTargetPath);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_fileWatcherTargetPath);
            }

            //Add folder path to file watcher
            watcher.Path = _fileWatcherTargetPath;
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

            //Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and the renaming of files or directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            GC.KeepAlive(watcher);

            SetTimer();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Is the directory you are watching on another machine?

Comment: Yes, i Was watching on the file system in another location

Comment: I've found the FileSystemWatcher to be generally unstable and it can 'break' easily if a large number of files comes in. I've all but stopped using it myself, and just implement a polling pattern instead. I guess you could do some programmatically check or just restart the service nightly as well.

Comment: Is there any problem with GC with filewatcher

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm now at the point where I create while(true){ DoAction(); Thread.Sleep(5000); } methods again.

Comment: The bug no doubt is in SetTimer(), timers are apt to get garbage-collected.  Just add GC.Collect() after that call to force the problem to occur early.

Comment: where do i need to add the GC.collect()

Comment: can anyone help me on this? I am still strucked